# Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in PresentationCore.dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have gone through many other questions on this error but couldn't resolve mine. So I am asking this from the professionals who can guide me how to resolve.

Here is the code which is giving me this error.

```
class MainClass
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        {
            Clock myClock = new Clock();

            while (myClock.Hour.Value < 24)
            {
                myClock.Tick();
                if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Space))
                {
                    myClock.ResetClock();
                }
            }
       
        Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The exception is showing after Key.Space

After going through stack I have added

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
```

below the static void even then it raised the error. Would be really great if you guys can throw some light on this issue and where and what shall I do to erase this and get my application to work. More info on this error also came.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred         in PresentationCore.dll
>
> Additional information: The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.

I am creating a C# clock through GUI.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why are you turning a console app into a GUI app?

Comment: Thanks All.. I manage to solve it

Comment: Goodo.  If your solution is different to those in the duplicate links, then feel free to post it as an answer.  You can earn reputation that way.  (it might have to be voted for reopening though)

Comment: How did you solve this?